# How can I configure Devise for Ruby on Rails to store the emails and passwords somewhere other than in the user model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise, ruby-on-rails-3

I'd like to store emails in a separate table and allow users to save multiple emails and log in with any of them. I'd also like to store passwords in a different table.

How can I configure Devise to store authentication info elsewhere?

Worst case scenario, if I just have to hack into it, is there a generator to just port everything over to the app? I noticed there was a generator for the views.

Comment: This is an old post, but what did you do to make this work when a user registers? (e.g., a before_save filter that creates the associated email records?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To do this, you have just to set up your models properly, create your email association. Also you have to override the user finder method from devise, to do this you have to override self.find_for_database_authentication(conditions) method.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :emails
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :emails
  ...
  def self.find_for_database_authentication(conditions)
    email = conditions.first
    self.where(:emails=>{:name=>email})
  end
end
```

Also you have to add the emails to your devise.rb to use it.

```
Devise.setup do |config|
  ...
  config.authentication_keys = [ :emails ]
  ...
end
```

**Update**

**First question:** Yes, the method from the devise will bee overrided automatically.

**Second question:** You should have your_application_path/config/initializers/devise.rb
I think it's created when you use the devise gem. If you don't have you can create it. The content I specified is good, just omit the dots (...)

Comment: I'm very new to rails (and programming), a couple questions before I attempt this: So if I write my own method with the same name as a gem into the model, it will automatically override the gem? Or do I have to strip it out of the gem as well? Also...in the second example, does this do in the external libraries/device/lib/devise.rb? I don't see a Devise.setup do |config| Thanks!

Comment: I'm also trying this, but what when the user registers?