# Adding multiple emails to the user model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I want to add multiple emails to the user model while using devise, using a has_many relationship.  It's a bit of an extension to this question: [How can I configure Devise for Ruby on Rails to store the emails and passwords somewhere other than in the user model?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4485993/913451)

User.rb
has_many :emails

Email.rb
belongs_to :user

In my new/edit form for devise how do I set up the fields_for xxx.email.  I can see that the registration page from devise uses "resource".  When I try the following code it just skips the email field.

```
= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| 
  = devise_error_messages! 
  %table{:style=>"width:400px;"}
    -fields_for resource.email do |emails|
      %tr 
        %td
          = emails.label :email
        %td
          = emails.email_field :email
  %tr
    %td
      = f.label :password ...
  %tr
    %td
      = f.label :firstname ....
```

Also, who do you modify the actions in the controller for devise?

In this case, the entire email block does not apear.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The helper `fields_for` need some data to create the fields. With new records, usually is needed you do something like `resource.emails.build` to create a first record to be showed.

And also, I think you should use `fields_for(resource.emails) do |email|`.