# How to associate multiple emails for a single user in rails Devise gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, rubygems

I am developing an application which uses `Devise` for user authentication. It performs all standard task that `Devise` handles (e.g.: Email verification during user sign up). But a user may have multiple email addresses to access his account and I want to verify all those addresses too.

My design is: user will get a email field in his profile page to add another email address to access his account along with his existing email address. After clicking submit, an email verification will occur like first time sign up process and user will be able to use both of this email address after successful verification.

Is there any gem available for this? If I need to implement it by myself, how can I do this without breaking the existing system?

Comment: This answer may be useful to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4485993/how-can-i-configure-devise-for-ruby-on-rails-to-store-the-emails-and-passwords-s

Comment: Do you need to enable logging in using the other emails too? or will you settle for logging in with a single 'primary' email?

Answer (score 3):

It's very late to reply but recently I faced similar issue and found one gem which lets user have many emails, user can login with any email, set one email as primary, and provides support for confirmable, authenticable and validatable for each email.

Here is the link  to gem:
https://github.com/allenwq/devise-multi_email

Hope it helps someone facing same situation :)